# Python3 logical left shift

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators, bit-shift

By default the 'left shift' operation in Python ( << ) acts as an arithmetic shift and appends a 0 bit to the end of the bits representing the int.

For example:
100 << 1 returns 200

In the binary representation we can see that 100 = 0b1100100 (7 bits) and 100 << 1 = 0b11001000 (8 bits)

In Python 3 what is the best way to perform a logical left shift where the number of bits stays constant, but the values are shifted to the left one?

For example:
100 << 1 would return 72

In the binary representation 100 = 0b1100100 and 100 << 1 = 0b1001000
We've kept the same 7 bits, but just shifted to the left one and appended a 0 to the end.

Comment: You could use the modulo operator: `(100 << 1) % 2**7` gives 72

Comment: You must restrict to the desired bits with an `&` operation after the shift, e. g. `& 2**7 - 1` for 7 bits.

Comment: A literal interpretation of your final paragraph is `int(bin(100)[3:]+'0',2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`int.bitlength`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) to get the number of bits required to represent the number, then `and` the result of the shift with `(1 << bitlength) - 1` to restrict the result to that many bits:

```
def lls_const_bits(n):
    return (n << 1) & ((1 << n.bit_length()) - 1)

print(lls_const_bits(100))
```

Output:

```
72
```

If you want to restrict the output to a fixed number of bits `b`, you would need to mask with `(1 << b) - 1`:

```
def lls_const_bits(n, b):
    return (n << 1) & ((1 << b) - 1)

print(lls_const_bits(100, 7))
```

Output:

```
72
```